# Outlook - Create rule or macro that runs when I flag an email - move to a "Flagged" folder and mark as unread

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, macros, rules, flag

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to create a rule or run a macro to accomplish the following:

- Ideally, this rule would run when I click the flag icon on an email
- It would move that item to a folder called "Flagged"
- It would mark that item as unread

A couple additional notes:

- I am using the downloaded desktop version of Office 365
- I know nothing about coding, VBA or macros but I'm willing to learn!
- I would also be satisfied with a button I could add to the Quick Access Toolbar to run it manually, if there's no way to run it when a flag is clicked.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is via the `Quick Steps` tool.

[image]

Click `Create New` from the ribbon bar, and use the following dialog to enter your process

[image]

I set this up as below

[image]

I now have a button in the `Quick Steps` region

[image]

You may want to edit or delete an existing quick step, or change the ordering so it appears on the ribbon bar.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! I'll be honest, I didn't really realize Quick Steps existed, this should mostly do what I'm looking for, with a small manual step in there. Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Feel free to tick it as the correct answer, and upvote whilst you're there.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, in outlook client, only the flagged messages can be moved to the specified folder through rules, and the object is the received or sent messages. It seems impossible that messages flagged manually would be moved to the specified folder and set to unread by rules created in outlook.

According to your description, I have done a lot of research and found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022595/outlook-macro-that-will-copy-an-email-i-flag-and-put-it-in-a-folder) about using macros to try to implement this feature. Because I mainly study the problems related to outlook client, I am not familiar with macro and VBA, just for reference.

Considering that you need to manage some messages that need to be completed within a specified date, as a workaround, it's suggested that you could create a custom search folder which Follow up messages can be displayed in a folder instead of being moved. For specific operation steps, please refer to:

1.Under Folder tab, click New search Folder;

2.In New search Folder window, under Custom, double click Create a custom Search Folder;

3.Type the name for this folder, such as Follow Up;

4.Click Criteria… , type the Due Date and choose the condition, such as tomorrow;

5.Under Mail from these folders will be included in this Search Folder, choose the folder where the flagged emails are from;
[image]

6. Click OK.

In addition, I notice that you are satisfied with spikey_richie's suggestion. It is suggested that you could mark helpful response as an answer so that people with the same questions can get help.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.